# Manhwa or manhua where the artist of an unpopular story gets hit by electricity and isekais into his story as a side character

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I remember this guy caused the hero to die and almost destroyed his manga world by saying he was the creator to the Demon King and everyone. Then he chose restart and had to keep the story going and try to make it popular this time. He had to finish the story well to get his body outside of the comic back and could see the likes and comments on each chapter.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall any names, or remember any details of the art or character appearance?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/jfky0n/author_isekaied_into_his_own_personally_created/ might be handy.

Comment: Hi thank you! I don't remember the site unfortunately but the art was your average manhwa format with nothing I can say as their speciality . The character had short brown hair with glasses as the artist and short messy brown hair as the Isekaied person. I remember when he reset story his character was sent to the point when he was a slave . He found some kind of spider monster that was a boss , fought it and leveled up by defeating it. Then beat the slavery boss and freed the slaves . That's as far as I had read and I think this was published this year so it might be less than 50 chapters now

Comment: Also https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/utcj2q/isekai_where_mc_is_an_authorworldbuilder_who_gets/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is ***[A Comic Artist's Survival Guide](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/m5spnki/a-comic-artist-s-survival-guide)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Snow, a failing comic artist whose comic is about to be discontinued, reincarnates into his own comic by chance. In his comic, the Pante Continent is on the verge of ruin due to the expansion of the Demon King’s army, resulting in Snow being in danger as well. Just as his life was about to end, Snow receives an opportunity to survive, with the condition that he takes over the author’s role and rewrites the entire comic’s storyline. If he fails to ” create” a more interesting story, then Snow and the comic world would be destroyed…

The protagonist, Xue Yingxue, is the artist of the manhua "The Hero Battles the Demon King". In the first chapter, his employers point out the declining sales figures, likes, comments and bookmarks of the manhua, and tell him that he'll be fired after he finishes the last chapter.

He's subsequently transported into his own story as a side character, during the Hero's battle with the Demon King. The Hero dies sacrificing himself to save Yingxue, and facing death himself at the hands of the Demon King, Yingxue exclaims that he created this world. This causes everything around him, including the Demon King, to start disintegrating into nothingness.

Then a status screen appears, informing Yingxue that he's spoken the forbidden words, causing the world around him to collapse. He's also informed that he can save himself and the world around him by resetting the entire story within the next three minutes, and so that's precisely what he does.

After that, he's informed that every action he makes will affect or change the plot of the story, which will in turn affect the ratings of the manhua, and so he resolves to make the plot more exciting than the original one in order to attract more readers.

[image] [image]